# If particles with a De Broglie wavelength similar to visible light was shot in to your eye, would you see colour?

Tags: visible-light

For instance, if a stream of electrons traveling at around 10<sup>6</sup> ms<sup>-1</sup> was shot into my eye what would I see?

Comment: I highly advise **not** to test this experimentally.

Answer (score 0):

For the eye to see light there must be an electronic transition in a photopsin photoreceptor proteine of the electric dipole type. Light corresponding to the molecular transition frequency can produce this through electric dipole transition. It is likely that electrons with an energy in a suitable range can also produce this transition through their electric field. Such electrons could also do a lot of damage in the process. Since the transition should be by inelastic collision, the energy probably should be higher than the molecular transition energy.